# Generate multi dimensional PHP array using range

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The job to be done is show the price of postage per KG. So starting at 1KG, I want to increase by 0.50 for every KG.

I tried doing it like this which doesn't seem to work for me:

```
$shipping_second_class = array (
array ('weight' => range(1,5), 'cost' => range(1,3, 0.50))
);

foreach ($shipping_second_class as $shipping_second_class) {
    echo('weight '.$shipping_second_class['weight'].' costs &pound;'.$shipping_second_class['cost'].'<br/>');
}
```

That doesn't seem to work. What I'm trying to do in a way that's easier to maintain is something like this, but with less code:

```
$shipping_second_class = array (
    array ('weight' => '1', 'cost' => '1'),
    array ('weight' => '2', 'cost' => '1.5'),
    array ('weight' => '3', 'cost' => '2'),
    array ('weight' => '4', 'cost' => '2.5'),
    array ('weight' => '5', 'cost' => '3'),
);

foreach ($shipping_second_class as $shipping_second_class) {
    echo('weight '.$shipping_second_class['weight'].' costs &pound;'.$shipping_second_class['cost'].'<br/>');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another simple way

```
$per_kg_extra_cost = 0.5;
foreach (range(0, 4) as $shipping) {
    $cost = 1 + ( $shipping * $per_kg_extra_cost ); 
    $weight = ++$shipping; 
    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'Weight: '. $weight . '   cost : ' .$cost;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do this:

```
$shipping_second_class = array (
array ('weight' => 1, 'cost' => 1)
);

for($x = 2; $x < 6; $x++){
    $newdata = ['weight' => $x, 'cost' => 0.5 + $x * 0.5];
    array_push($shipping_second_class, $newdata);
}

foreach ($shipping_second_class as $s) {
    echo('weight '.$s['weight'].' costs &pound;'.$s['cost'].'<br/>');
}
```

Essentially, you need to add to the array after it's been called rather than initialize it fully filled. You start with the array at 1 value (you could modify this code to start with an empty array) and it expands from there. If you need to add more to the array, just increase the 6 to `(Desired Number) + 1` in the for loop.

I'm not sure if there is a way to add to the array in the manner you do in the first block of code.

Comment: Just a note, this isn't the perfect way to write it, I would suggest improving it to fit your use.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
$key = -1;
$interval = 0.5;
$shipping_second_class = array_map(function($v) use (&$key,$interval) {
 $key++;
 return ["weight"=>$v,"cost"=>(1 + ($interval * $key))];                              
},range(1,5));

echo json_encode($shipping_second_class);
```

You can change the $interval variable if you need to change the way it increments cost